# iPhone: Issue when adding 60 days from the current date in milliseconds

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add 60 days from the current date in milliseconds. I tried the below code, i'm able to get the current date milliseconds properly, but after adding 60 days milliseconds to current date, its not giving me the expected milliseconds. Please help on correcting what i'm doing wrong here.

```
double currDateInMilliSecs = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000;    
NSLog(@"currDateInMilliSecs: %f", currDateInMilliSecs);

double sixtydaysvalue = 60 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
NSLog(@"sixtydaysvalue: %f", sixtydaysvalue);

double sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate = currDateInMilliSecs + sixtydaysvalue;
NSLog(@"sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate: %f", sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate);
```

Thank you.

Comment: 60*24*3600*1000 will overflow a 32 bit integer, I suspect that the compiler is doing interger math then assigning the result to the double sixtydaysvalue, try making the maths be 60.0*24*3600*1000 to force floating point maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
double sixtydaysvalue = 60.0 * 24.0 * 3600.0 * 1000.0;
```

The value exceeds the max 32-bit int, so you need to perform the calculation in the `double` type.

Answer (score 0):

You wil try this

```
 NSTimeInterval sixtydaysvalue = 60 * 24 * 3600 * 1000.0
```